# Two Dice game of pig can't get score to reset

Tags: python, if-statement, return-value, dice

here is a code I found online. I modified it to roll two dice instead of one, but I'm having trouble getting the score to reset to 0 when snake eyes are rolled. I have tried a few things like reassigning my original values from top to reset the score to 0 but did not work. I'm just at a loss.

```
from random import randint

playercount = 2
maxscore = 100
safescore = [0] * playercount
player = 0
score=0

while max(safescore) < maxscore:
    if player == 0:
        rolling = 0
        if score < 17 and score + safescore[player] < maxscore:
            rolling = 1
    else:
        rolling = input("Player %i: (%i, %i) Rolling? (Y) "
            % (player, safescore[player], score)).strip().lower() in {'yes', 'y', ''}
    if rolling:
        rolled = randint(1, 6)
        rolled2 = randint(1, 6)
        print('  Rolled %i' % rolled)
        print('  Rolled %i' % rolled2)
        if rolled ==1 and rolled2 ==1:
                print('  Snake Eyes!! your score is set to 0')

                score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount
        elif rolled == 1:
            print('  Bust! you lose %i but still keep your previous %i'
                  % (score, safescore[player]))
            score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount
        elif rolled2 == 1:
            print('  Bust! you lose %i but still keep your previous %i'
                  % (score, safescore[player]))
            score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount


        else:
            score += rolled + rolled2
    else:
        safescore[player] += score
        if safescore[player] >= maxscore:
            break
        print('  Sticking with %i' % safescore[player])
        score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount

print('\nPlayer %i wins with a score of %i' %(player, safescore[player]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out this is how it needed to be fixed.

```
if rolled ==1 and rolled2 ==1:
                print('  Snake Eyes!! your score is set to 0')
                safescore[player] = 0    
                player = (player + 1) % playercount
```